# Is Google's Developer Documentation tooling public?

Tags: documentation-generator

Did Google publish their public developer documentation tooling/generators? I'm talking about the documentation available from the  `https://developers.google.com/` family of URLs. E.g. https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/overview or https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/gettingstarted_app.

All of their developer documentation is obviously consistently styled, and seems to include lots of machine-generated content.

The closest I found to a public variant of this tooling is in the [Web Fundamentals](https://github.com/google/WebFundamentals) sources. Is that it? Or is there a more canonical source for the tooling?

Answer (score 1):

Google's documentation magic sauce doesn't seem to be publicly available from a single source.

Not all of Google's open source projects have equally open-source documentation. E.g. [protobuf](https://github.com/google/protobuf)'s documentation is not open-source (or at least my google-fu has failed here) - it's only available in compiled form at https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/.

The documentation build system is included with several projects, though. The list below aims to be a canonical list of Google OSS projects that include their documentation:

- [Polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/) - sources at: https://github.com/Polymer/docs/
- [Web Fundamentals](https://developers.google.com/web/fndamentals/) - sources at: https://github.com/google/WebFundamentals/